# Customize Activity Stream - Buddypress

Tags: buddypress

Where would I begin if I wanted to rename a string in the buddypress activity stream?

Instead of it saying "so and so wrote a new post", I would like it to say "so and so wrote a new **article**" (or whatever word I choose)

Thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it

```
add_filter('bp_blogs_activity_new_post_action', 'record_cpt_activity_action', 1, 3);
function record_cpt_activity_action( $activity_action,  $post, $post_permalink ) { 
    global $bp;
    if( $post->post_type == 'post' ) {
        if ( is_multisite() )
            $activity_action  = sprintf( __( '%1$s wrote a new article, %2$s, on the site %3$s', 'buddypress' ), bp_core_get_userlink( (int) $post->post_author ), '<a href="' . $post_permalink . '">' . $post->post_title . '</a>', '<a href="' . get_blog_option( $blog_id, 'home' ) . '">' . get_blog_option( $blog_id, 'blogname' ) . '</a>' );

        else
               $activity_action  = sprintf( __( '%1$s wrote a new article, %2$s', 'buddypress' ), bp_core_get_userlink( (int) $post->post_author ), '<a href="' . $post_permalink . '">' . $post->post_title . '</a>' );

    }

    return $activity_action;
}
```